# How do I find the last Xth day using PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I'd like to get the timestamp of the last Xth day, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to quantify what you mean by "Xth" day.

Comment: Oh, now it's clear. He wants to know when the last time X day occured. If the day is in the future for the current month, return the date string for that day in the last month it occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$X`th day of the month?

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), $x, date('Y'));
```

Most recent `$X`th day of the month?

```
if(date('j') >= $x)
    return mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), $x, date('Y'));
else
   return mktime( 0, 0, 0, date('n') - 1, $x, date('Y'));
```

Comment: the wrong date will be returned if the `$x` day falls in December and the current day is January

Comment: @RDL, whoops, that's fixed. @Patrick: will it? I thought `mktime` would fix up the month and year for me (it definitely will fix the month.)

Comment: you are correct.  mktime will fix the date properly for you across years too.

Answer (score 1):

if you want $x number of days back, just do:

```
$timestampxdaysback = time() - (86400 * $x);
                                // 86400 seconds in a day
```

Comment: No, not X number of days back. What I need is the last Xth month. For instance, if X = 14, the result would be 14/03/11. If X = 25, the result would be 25/02/2011.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the last day of a month then use:

```
echo date('d', mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,0,$year));
```

Where `$month` is the month you want the last day of.  The '0' in the `day` position is what does the trick.  Think of it as the 'yesterday' option.

**update**

```
if ($x > date('d') {
  $date = mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,$x,date('Y'));
} else {
  $date = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$x,date('Y'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work:

```
function getXthMonth($x)
{
    $current_month  = date("m", time());
    $current_day    = date("d", time());
    $current_year   = date("Y", time());

    if($x <= $current_day)
        return $current_month.'/'.$x.'/'.$current_year;
    else
    {
        if($current_month > 1)
        {
            $current_month--;
            return $current_month.'/'.$x.'/'.$current_year;
        }
        else
        {
            $current_year--;
            return '12/'.$x.'/'.$current_year;
        }
    }
}
```